# How to create following user interface in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone tell me how to create following interface in android ?

When one row is full the next textBoxes must be in next line. But the problem I'm facing is that the length of text is dynamic, So can't calculate the width.

[image: following]

Comment: Well, what have you done so far?

Comment: I just have a look on this  https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library library, but not enough expert to customize it according to my needs:

Comment: The idea behind using EditText was that, it can put textboxes in next row by calculating width by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the FlowLayout [FlowLayout in github](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

It's a Linear layout, that wrap its content to the next line if there is no space in the current line.

Comment: Thanks, just let me try this...!

Comment: Your link was helpful, but that didn't work for me... My problem was solved by this link : https://gist.github.com/hzqtc/7940858